# Proper punctuation of equations

Tags: publications, mathematics, writing-style

What is the proper way to punctuate equations following a colon (:)?

Is it:

> The Pythagorean Theorem can be expressed as the following equation:
>
> $a^2+b^2=c^2$
>
> In number theory, triples satisfying the aforementioned condition are known as Pythagorean triples.

Or

> The Pythagorean Theorem can be expressed as the following equation:
>
> $a^2+b^2=c^2$**.**
>
> In number theory, triples satisfying the aforementioned condition are known as Pythagorean triples.

(The difference is the period after the equation)

Comment: Do you mean "following a colon"? And are you just asking about the period or something else?

Comment: Of course. And yes.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4669669/442 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/6675/454 for the same question in other forums.

Comment: Neither is correct. Equations are part of the text, and are read like text. Just say “The Pythagorean theorem states that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.” No colon required, and obviously a period follows because it ends the sentence.

Comment: What you are doing is like saying: “Ecosystems are studied within a subfield of biology whose name is denoted by the following word: ecology.” It doubles the length of the sentence for no reason. Just say “Ecosystems are studied in ecology.”

Comment: @knzhou But some equations don’t fit in text.

Comment: Then write "The Pythagorean theorem states that $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2.$$."

Answer (score 8):

As the other answers indicate, opinions differ on the matter. If you are writing with a particular venue in mind, check their style guide.

For example, the [Physical Review Style and Notation Guide](https://cdn.journals.aps.org/files/styleguide-pr.pdf) says

> Punctuate mathematical expressions as sentences
> or parts of sentences.

The [guide for the American Chemical Society](https://pubsapp.acs.org/paragonplus/submission/acs_math-stylesheet.pdf), on the other hand, says that inline equations should be punctuated as text

> In-text equations are punctuated as parts of the sentences in
> which they are contained, including closing punctuation.

but not in display equations

> End punctuation is not used in display equations.

My impression is that maths/computer science generally recommend puntuation after display equations while chemistry/engineering generally don't use such punctuation, but I did not perform a thorough analysis checking every journal in each field.

Comment: This is what I think is the right answer. Treat formulas -- inlined or offset -- as part of the sentence, and then punctuate them as if you had written the formula out in words.

Answer (score 4):

European languages suggest the period belongs. It has nothing to do with math. Few will notice, I'd guess, since you write on separate lines so the line breaks serve as "something like" the period, separating thoughts. A copy editor would probably supply it if you don't.

And few mathematicians would think the period was part of the equation in such a case, though it might be different ins some others.

Comment: So, even tho the equation is preceded by a colon, it is probably OK to put a period?

Comment: Yes, of course. Better to include it actually. You are writing in "sentences", not tables and such.

Comment: For what it's worth, I sometimes exclude the period when the mathematical stuff at the end of the sentence is displayed, and I'm even more likely to do so when there is a colon used as in the OP's version. I'm also more likely to do so when the mathematical stuff is fairly elaborate/long. But if co-authors are involved or copy editors are later involved . . .

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, the audience is unlikely to object if they are actually mathematicians and not students. It is important to make the intent clear _somehow_, that the end has been reached. But it isn't the same a prose. And poetry seldom uses periods.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro In that context, I  meant if one chooses to follow such a convention, would a dot after a colon be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I don't think either of your suggested alternatives is good typesetting. In each case you have three paragraphs, one of which consists only of an inline equation. You should either make the first two into a single paragraph, or use a displayed equation, i.e. one of the following.

> The Pythagorean Theorem can be expressed as the following equation: `$a^2+b^2=c^2$`.

> The Pythagorean Theorem can be expressed as the following equation:
> `\[a^2+b^2=c^2.\]`

Some people would omit the period in the second example, but that is not because of the colon. It is because they would omit the period after any displayed equation.

The colon doesn't change anything. In English, whatever follows a colon still ends with a period (or other appropriate punctuation mark such as "?"). So you should not treat this any differently than if you had said "The Pythagorean Theorem says that ..." followed by a displayed or inline equation as you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

There are varying opinions. :)  As in other comments and answers, there are rationales for including or not including the period. The colon preceding is irrelevant. Perhaps the "most popular" choice is to include the period... or other punctuation, such as commas and semi-colons, depending how the sentence may continue. (I admit that I do not like English punctuation in displayed mathematics.)

Apart from convention, there is indeed the practical issue of knowing whether or not a display is end-of-sentence. For me, since a period introduces a bit of visual noise (usually trivial, but not reliably so), the way I would signal end-of-sentence is to start the text after the display with a capitalized (English) word, as opposed to further mathematical symbols. If the after-display text is a continuation of the sentence, then likewise make this clear by having a not-capitalized (English) word before further mathematical symbols.

Yes, some co-authors and editors will coerce adding the period, so it's not worth spending toooo much time making choices based on one's personal aesthetic, if it's going to be subject to conformification *anyway* :)

Comment: (+1) *For me, since a period introduces a bit of visual noise (usually trivial, but not reliably so)* --- This is the background rationale for the things I said in my earlier comment here. (Just to be clear -- upon rereading my comment now, I see that I should have been more explicit -- in the places where I said "more likely to do so", I mean I'm more likely to EXCLUDE the period.)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, :)

Comment: For journals, this is often a matter of written down fact in the style sheet.  Different journals/publishers will have different implementations.  Also, publication staff will fix up most author errors in processing -- so getting it "right" isn't necessarily critical.

Answer (score 1):

The [American Mathematical Society Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) (p 100) reads

> Each mathematics equation reads as a clause or sentence and is punctuated accordingly. Authors, however, sometimes leave displayed math
> unpunctuated. Insert commas and periods as needed so that the equation(s), the preceding text, and the following text together read grammatically.

So

> `The Pythagorean theorem can be expressed as the following equation: \[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \]`

is correct for AMS publications (note the period at the end of the displayed equation).  Note that *neither* of the options presented in the question is quite right, as those examples use a single dollar-sign delimiter, indicated inline mathematics.  In that case, the most correct typesetting would be

> `The Pythagorean theorem can be expressed as the following equation: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.`

Note that the period occurs *after* the closing delimiter.  This won't make a ton of difference in the final typeset document, but it can make a perceptible difference in some contexts.

Comment: *Note that the period occurs after the closing delimiter.* --- I nearly always put the period INSIDE the right-side math delimiter (LaTeX documents, math related Stack Exchange groups, MathType in MS Word documents, etc.) to avoid the possibility of a new line starting with a period, which CAN happen, especially in SE questions/answers/comments and in MS Word documents.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Yeah, those are issues I have not encountered.  LaTeX typically won't allow a line to start with a period, and most (all?) AMS journals expect LaTeX submissions.  I can't speak to what MS Word or Google Docs or whatever will do, but that might also not be relevant to my answer, as if you *aren't* using LaTeX, you probably don't need to abide by the AMS style, and can do whatever you like. :D

Comment: @DaveLRenfro In Latex documents your practice is the opposite of what Knuth recommends in the TeXbook: "spacing rules within paragraphs work best when the punctuation marks are not considered to be part of the formulas". See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149651/is-it-more-common-to-type-period-inside-dollars-or-outside

Comment: @Adam Přenosil: To be honest, I don't know for sure whether a line break could occur just before a period in my LaTeX documents (in case it makes a difference, I've been using "Scientific Word/Workplace" since 1994), but it can definitely break just before a period in the SE groups MSE, mathoverflow, Mathematics Educators as well as in several of the programs I have to use in my jobs since Aug 2005 ([1](https://www.excelsoftcorp.com/products/testing-and-assessment-products/saras-schools-and-universities/), [2](https://www.wiris.com/en/mathtype/), and a few other such tools).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Sure, I imagine there are various contexts where that's the right thing to do. But in ordinary (La)Tex documents I would trust Knuth.